# Sync SQL Server CE 4 database data with server everyday

Tags: c#, sql-server, synchronization

I have an application on my local which is installed on different computers which is using `SQL Server CE 4 (.sdf)`  database.

So what I want is, I need the data of that application to be merged on a single centralized database (Which can be on one of our online server which has `SQL Server 2008` database) so that I can review it and can take some decisions.

Can anyone let me know which method will work in this situation.?

Comment: One option is Microsoft Sync Framework. I have also considered different options for this scenario and found out, that Sync framework adds a lot of tables to the database, so I ended up using my own sync routines that are using timestamp (rowversion) columns.

Comment: I would go with [Sync Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb726002(v=sql.110).aspx)

Comment: There is also “Merge replication” avaliable, supposing you do not have problems with licensing and CALs. But both Sync Framework and Merge replication are overkill for simple copying new data to central database. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlservercompact/archive/2009/11/09/merge-replication-vs-sync-services-for-compact.aspx

Comment: Both Sync Framework and Merge Replication are not supported on SQL CE 4.0 (see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg592946.aspx) if you want, there's an unsupported way of getting Sync Fx to work with SQL CE 4 (see: http://jtabadero.wordpress.com/2012/04/20/sync-framework-and-sql-compact-4-yes-you-can/)